# worldmap with wrong parameters for colours

Tags: r

I want to switch my worldmap parameters. This currently prints in most cases more lightblue. I want exactly the opposite. I got this code on Google, so have no idea how to work with it. Can anyone help me?

```
world_map = map_data("world") %>% 
  filter(! long > 180)

countries = world_map %>% 
  distinct(region) %>% 
  rowid_to_column()

countries %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = rowid, map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(map = world_map) +
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat) +
  coord_map("moll") +
  theme_map()
```

Comment: May I ask if you can please elaborate on your ask. Do you just want the opposite effect? If so, you see where you do `fill = rowid`, change that to `fill = -rowid` and re-run. Let me know if that's what you intended.

Comment: 'more lightblue, i want exactly the opposite' : what do you mean by 'the opposite'?

Comment: Add the loading of the packages, please